# Avoid the use of .data segment

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, shellcode

Is there a way to avoid that the compiled code use the .data segment? Is it possible to write a C code and use compiler options to force everything to be in .text?
The reason I ask is because I want to put the assembly code of another program in the stack and run the code from there. So it will not work if this program is using the data segment.

Comment: If you have no global variables, and use no libraries that have global variables, then there won't be anything in the data segment. (Note that that's overly restrictive; global variables declared as const and global variables without initializers are likely to be in other segments anyway.)

Comment: Why do you think not using `.data` will allow running code from the stack? Why do you think using `.data` will prevent it?

Comment: It would be interesting to know what the original problem is.  What you are doing seems like a hack.  I have the feeling that if we knew what the original problem was, we could possibly offer a solution that doesn't involve load an assemble program into the stack.  What is it you are trying to accomplish and why?

Comment: A bytecode from program A that is supposed to be loaded from program B. Program B encrypts/decrypts the code from program A and run it from the stack. I don't want to write the whole program A in assembler, but in C. Thus the issue here.

Comment: Why stack? Define some executable section in the linker script and load the code there using `__attribute__((section("name"))`

Comment: @EugeneSh.: sounds like the OP wants to use compiler output to make shellcode that can be used for code-injection.  (e.g. by overflowing a stack buffer, in a legacy program with an executable stack).  Everything needs to be in one blob of bytes, basically a flat binary, and position-independent.  You can manually edit the compiler's asm output to put `.rodata` or even `.data` in with `.text` of course, if the target has PC-relative addressing (like x86-64).

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a way to avoid that the compiled code use the .data segment?

There'd be multiple ways - writing code that simply doesn't use data; using compiler specific extensions (e.g. "`__attribute__((section("name")))`" in GCC), writing a linker script that causes everything in the input file's `.data` and `.rodata` sections to be shoved into the output file's `.text` section; having a whole new section called `.myData` that isn't called `.data`, etc.

> Is it possible to write a C code and use compiler options to force everything to be in .text?

Yes, anything is possible if you want to spend years writing your own compiler, etc.

The problem is that this is about permissions. Modern CPUs allow the OS to say "this area of memory is not executable" or "this area of memory is not modifiable", and have that enforced by hardware to catch bugs and avoid security disasters. Sections are how you tell the OS what the permissions should be (e.g. executable and read-only `.text`, not executable and read-only `.rodata`, not executable and modifiable `.data`). By breaking that you end up with something worse than necessary (less chance of detecting bugs, more chance of security disasters).

It can also cause performance problems for the CPU (half of "L1 instruction cache" wasted caching data, half of "L1 data cache" wasted caching instructions, CPU think it's self-modifying code because you wrote to something in the same cache line or same page as instructions).

> The reason I ask is because I want to put the assembly code of another program in the stack and run the code from there.

Typically the stack is "not executable" so it'll probably just crash. To fix that you'll probably need special code to change the permission of the area of memory used by stack, but if you can modify the other program to do that then you can also modify the other program to include the assembly directly and avoid the need for silly nonsense.

Comment: The memory used will have the permission for execution

Comment: @LuHell: Then, at best, it'll be a pointless performance disaster.

Comment: Still not clear what not having `.data` has to do with it.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: There's 2 cases - not having any data at all, and having data but not having a `.data` section (e.g. putting the data into `.text` instead). I'm trying to cover both cases; but there's very little to say about not having any data at all, and it's likely the question wouldn't have been asked if there was no data (because why would you care about an empty section?); so most discussion ends up being for the "having data but not having a `.data` section" case (and how to do that, and the consequences of doing that).

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the you want to use compiler output to make shellcode that can be used for code-injection.  (e.g. by overflowing a stack buffer, in a legacy program with an executable stack).

Yes, everything needs to be in one blob of bytes, basically a flat binary, and position-independent.

**You can manually edit the compiler's asm output to put `.rodata` and even `.data` in with `.text`**.  You can test this in a stand-alone executable by compiling linking with `ld -N` (`--omagic`) to make `.text` writeable.

Of course, that only works if the ISA you're compiling for has PC-relative addressing, like x86-64 but not 32-bit x86.  Using labels for memory operands in 32-bit x86 will lead to absolute addresses in the machine code, which obviously can't work when injecting into the stack at an unknown address.

(Related: `-zexecstack` makes all memory executable, so code-injection attacks can work.  This is not the default; code injection doesn't work on systems that maintain W^X (no pages that are both writeable and executable).)

---

**So really what you should do is just not use any library functions, and not use any globals or `static` variables.**  i.e. write code that doesn't use any variable with static storage class, only automatic.  Use a local array if you need a small buffer.

You also need to use  inline asm wrapper macros for system calls, not the usual libc wrapper functions.

Comment: When moving the .rodata and .data into .text, the code still have  hard coded references to the adresses there. I am not injecting the code in some other program. Both codes are mine, and I can ensure the whole memory is executable.

Comment: @LuHell: This answer explicitly says that only works for ISAs where static data is addressed in a PC-relative manner, like x86-64.  (But there it *does* work. e.g. `mov eax, [RIP + my_label]` (GAS .intel_syntax) is position-independent when assembled for x86-64.)  For ISAs without PC-relative data addressing, you need to make sure you write code that compiles without any references to labels other than relative branches.